I have assembled raw short RNA-seq reads into Transcripts using Trinity. My raw reads were strand-specific. What should I set "--strand" in Diamond?
I used Trinity to de-novo assemble my RNA seq raw reads. These reads were generated using a strand-specific method. Now I want to do a BLASTx using Diamond. I am unsure what I should keep under its argument "--strand". Basically, it has three options:

Plus - if reads align in the forward sense
Minus - if read align in the reverse sense
Both - if you want to align in both ways

The problem is that I don't know if Trinity preserved my information on strand-specificity when constructing its Transcripts. If it did, I can happily choose Plus, I suppose. Any help would be... helpful.

Trinity should be assembling its transcripts in the forward sense direction, so as long as you can be confident in your assembly, you can use the Plus option for the --strand argument.
More generally, when there are a few options to choose from and you're not sure which one is more appropriate, try running a small subset of the data using all options and look at the results. I find that such a results-based checking can help me more quickly understand my data when the documentation is unclear.
